# Extrange behaviour from echo inside a while read

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to iterate a file with this code:

```shell
#!/bin/bash

filename='ids.txt'
echo Start
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "$line":
done < $filename
```

The shell outputs `:EXTFROMLINE` instead what I would expect: `TEXTFROMLINE:`. It seems to put the last character (`:`) as the first and overwrite the first character.

What could be wrong?

Comment: *"What could be wrong?"* your `ids.txt` file could have DOS-style (CRLF) line endings

Comment: That was exactly the cause. Weird because all my editors are configured to use LF line endings. Why don't you post it as an answer to mark it as solved? :)